# merge multiple CSV files in one CSV file and create super schema in final CSV file using unix shell script or unix awk

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to merge multiple CSV files into one CSV file using the UNIX shell script. The final CSV file contains super schema columns(all columns from each file). non-available column values consider for empty value or blank space value in the final CSV file.

Example:

```
file111.csv:
"E_TYPE","TIMESTAMP","EXEC_TIME","DBT_TIME","CALLOUT_TIME","CLIENT_IP"
"BBCout","20191011000022.423","95","0","2019-01-11T00:00:05.300Z","200.50.000.333" 
"BBCout","20200403122024.123","96","1","2020-04-03T00:00:05.300Z","300.50.000.333"
"BBCout","20210102083426.543","92","0","2021-01-02T00:00:05.300Z","400.50.000.333"
```

```
file222.csv:
"E_TYPE","TIMESTAMP","TYPE","METHOD","TIME","RT_SIZE","URL","UID_DERIVED","CLIENT_IP"
"AACallout","20210215000030.815","REST","POST","61","71","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055QAQ","200.50.000.333"
"AACallout","20201210000012.800","REST","GET","67","75","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055BBBQ","300.00.000.111"
```

final merged CSV should contain all columns and non-available columns should be empty values or blank space.

```
final CSV file:
"E_TYPE","TIMESTAMP","CLIENT_IP","EXEC_TIME","DBT_TIME","CALLOUT_TIME","TYPE","METHOD","TIME","RT_SIZE","URL","UID_DERIVED"
"BBCout","20191011000022.423","200.50.000.333","95","0","2019-01-11T00:00:05.300Z",,,,,,
"BBCout","20200403122024.123","300.50.000.333","96","1","2020-04-03T00:00:05.300Z",,,,,,
"BBCout","20210102083426.543","400.50.000.333","92","0","2021-01-02T00:00:05.300Z",,,,,,
"AACallout","20210215000030.815","200.50.000.333",,,,"REST","POST","61","71","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055QAQ"
"AACallout","20201210000012.800","300.00.000.111",,,,"REST","GET","67","75","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055BBBQ"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: The E_TYPE, TIMESTAMP and CLIENT_IP field names are common to both files.  Do you need all three to match for the lines to be combined?  If not, what are the criteria for joining lines?  How does the script know which columns to combine?  Does it need to deduce the common field names?  How should the output fields be ordered?  In many ways, your data is uninteresting since the sets of lines are completely disjoint — the common fields never have any values in common.  Is that going to be the case for all versions of the data?  (In SQL terms, what you're seeking is an 'outer join' of the files.)

Comment: There is no common joining column. Data complete union common columns should be exist dataset. non- common column null or empty value in output file.

Comment: there is no common joining dataset all the datasets need to add in a single file with all the columns.
Example: 
```
first.csv
---------
col1,col2,col3,col4
10,20,aaa,data
20,30,ccc,dttt

Second.csv
----------
col1,col5,col6
30,rrr,ggg
40,nnn,mmf

result.csv
-----------
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
10,20,aaa,data,null,null
20,30,ccc,dt,null,null
30,null,null,null,rrr,ggg
40,null,null,null,nnn,mmf
```